# Django serializer test post of file with user information

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I try to test a file upload like this:

```
@deconstructible
class FileGenerator:

    @staticmethod
    def generate_text_file(file_ending='txt'):
        file_content = b'some test string'
        file = io.BytesIO(file_content)
        file.name = f'test.{file_ending}'
        file.seek(0)
        return file

def test_this(self, api_client, login_as):
    user = login_as('quality-controller')
    url = reverse('test-list')
    organization = Organization(name="test")
    organization.save()

    data = {
        "organization": organization.id,
        "import_file": FileGenerator.generate_text_file('txt'),
        "user": {
            "id": user.id,
            "username": user.username,
        }
    }

    response = api_client.post(url, data, format='json')
```

But I receive the following error message:

> b'{"import_file": ["The submitted data was not a file. Check the
> encoding type on the form."]}'

I also tried to use: `format='multipart'` but then I receive the following error:

> AssertionError: Test data contained a dictionary value for key 'user',
> but multipart uploads do not support nested data. You may want to
> consider using format='json' in this test case.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is `FileGenerator`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM, I added the file generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I deal with this issue:

#### Simplest: flatten the form

Suck it up and just remove the issue by making your serializer to use `user_id` and `user_username` and fix it up on the server side in the serializer's `validate(self, attrs)` method.  A bit ugly/hacky but it works just fine and can be documented.

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    attrs["user"] = {
        "id": attrs.pop("user_id"), 
        "name": attrs.pop("user_username")
    }
    return attrs
```

#### Nicest if you dont mind the size: B64 Fields

You can base64 encode the `file` field and pass it in the json.  Then to decode it on the server side you would write (or search for) a simple [`Base64FileField()`](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields#base64imagefield) for DRF.

```
class UploadedBase64ImageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = Base64ImageField(required=False)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

#### Alternative - Flatten the form data

You can't pass nested data, but you **can** flatten the nested `dict`s and pass that to a DRF service.  Serializers actually *can* understand nested data if the field names are correct.

I don't know if this field name format is standardized, but this is what worked for me after experimentation.  I only use it for service->service communication TO drf, so you would have to clone it into JS, but you can use the python in unit tests.  Let me know if it works for you.

```
def flatten_dict_for_formdata(input_dict, array_separator="[{i}]"):
    """
    Recursively flattens nested dict()s into a single level suitable
    for passing to a library that makes multipart/form-data posts.
    """

    def __flatten(value, prefix, result_dict, previous=None):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            # If we just processed a dict, then separate with a "."
            # Don't do this if it is an object inside an array.  
            # In that case the [:id] _is_ the separator, adding 
            # a "." like list[1].name will break but list[x]name 
            # is correct (at least for DRF/django decoding)
            if previous == "dict":
                prefix += "."

            for key, v in value.items():
                __flatten(
                    value=v,
                    prefix=prefix + key,
                    result_dict=result_dict,
                    previous="dict"
                )
        elif isinstance(value, list) or isinstance(value, tuple):
            for i, v in enumerate(value):
                __flatten(
                    value=v,
                    prefix=prefix + array_separator.format(i=i),  # e.g. name[1]
                    result_dict=result_dict,
                    previous="array"
                )
        else:
            result_dict[prefix] = value

        # return her to simplify the caller's life.  ignored during recursion
        return result_dict

    return __flatten(input_dict, '', OrderedDict(), None)
```

```
# flatten_dict_for_formdata({...}):
{                                   # output field name
    "file": SimpleUploadFile(...),  # file
    "user": {                       
        "id": 1,                    # user.id
        "name": "foghorn",          # user.name        
        "jobs": [                           
            "driver",               # user.jobs[0]
            "captain",              # user.jobs[1]
            "pilot"                 # user.jobs[1]
        ]
    },
    "objects": [
        {
            "type": "shoe",         # objects[0]type
            "size": "44"            # objects[0]size
        },
    ]
}
```